# DBref data not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose model schema like this and already have data in MongoDB, I want to just call it with the `find()` method based on the desired parameters.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const sessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    day: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    start_time: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    end_time: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    student: [
      {
        type: String,
        ref: 'USERS',
      },
    ],
    subject: {
      type: String,
      ref: 'SUBJECTS',
      required: true,
    },
    lecturer: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    classroom: {
      type: String,
      ref: 'CLASSROOM',
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { collection: 'SESSION' }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('SESSION', sessionSchema);
```

and I try to display the contents of the database with the model like this:

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const Session = require('../models/sessionModel');

const listSession = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const session = await Session.find({ 'student.$id': req.user._id });
  if (session) {
    res.status(200).json({ session });
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }
});

module.exports = { listSession };
```

Why when I run the code it only displays "_id" and "lecturer" with correct user._id? all objects that have ref not showing (student and subject)?

The expected result of the code is to display all JSON according to the mongoose schema model

Answer (score 0):

You should [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) references:

```
await Session.find({ 'student.$id': req.user._id })
    .populate('student')
    .populate('subject')
    .populate('classroom')
    .exec();
```